# MonetDB error when starting mclient, cannot set locale

Tags: database, installation, locale, monetdb

I installed MonetDB on a Ubuntu 16.04 using the instructions: https://www.monetdb.org/easy-setup/ubuntu-debian/

When trying to start the client: `mclient -u monetdb -d testdb`

I get back this error:

> monetdbd: internal error while starting mserver 'database 'testdb' appears to shut itself down after starting, check monetdbd's logfile (merovingian.log) for possible hints'

and when I look inside the logfile I see that the problem is apparently related to the locale:

> "2022-01-19 17:47:18 ERR testdb[15411]: cannot set locale"

Any hints?

Comment: I googled about this error message for Ubuntu, I wonder if general information such as discussed on this site might help: https://askubuntu.com/questions/162391/how-do-i-fix-my-locale-issue

Answer (score 0):

The error message occurs only once in the code, so we can see exactly which call fails.  The failing call is

```
setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "")
```

and the call is done by mserver5.
The call is to set the locale for character types to whatever the environment specifies (i.e. a combination of the LC_LANG, LC_CTYPE, and LANG environment variables).  It seems that they are set incorrectly in your environment.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but could you clarify what is considered as incorrect setting? When I type locale, I see:

LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8 
...
LC_ALL=

Everything is "en_US.UTF-8". I don't see LC_LANG anywhere.

Comment: The relevant environment is that of the mserver5 process.  In your case, it is started by monetdbd, presumably under the control of systemd.  You should find out its environment.
The values you list seem fine, but as I said, they are not the relevant ones.